# How to get a password back?

Tags: password

I disabled my user password, then wanted to get a password back on, but Ubuntu 12.10 would not let me. It wants me to enter a previous password, but there is no previous password. Any ideas of what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own password from the command line even if you disabled it.

```
sudo passwd -u bogus //To unlock the password in case you blocked it
sudo passwd bogus
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

You may want to know the status of the passwords:

```
sudo passwd --status --all //Use --all in case you aren't logged as the user
```